# Trace context switches on Linux

Tags: linux, performance, trace, context-switch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitoring pthread context switching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914187/monitoring-pthread-context-switching)

I have a program where under certain scheduling layout some strange things happen (a number of threads which do sched_yield seem to throttle each other in a strange manner).

I would like to take an exact trace of what is going on in terms of the OS scheduler slices on each CPU.  Is there a way to capture such trace?  I'm running SLES 11.1, with root privileges.

Comment: or [Any approach to show threads switch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906690/any-approach-to-show-threads-switch)

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTTng) might be what you are looking for.